# Significance of regression coefficients and their equality

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing

Suppose, we want to regress $y$ on $x_1$ and $x_2$, i.e.

$$ y = \alpha + \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2 + \varepsilon \hspace{1cm} (1)$$

Is it, in principle, possible that simultaneously:

- $\beta_1$ is statistically significant but $\beta_2$ is *not* while
- $\beta_1$ statistically equals to $\beta_2$

?

Comment: What do you mean by "statistically equal"? If you mean $\hat{\beta}_1$ and $\hat{\beta}_2$ have the same estimated distribution, then no, it's not possible. If you mean that the point estimates $\hat{\beta}_1 = \hat{\beta}_2$ then yes it's possible.

Comment: I mean statistically equal according to some test, that means point estimates. I understand that running the same regression on different simulated data I can get this result, but is it possible to get it systematically? If so, how should I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes.**  This answer interprets the question in the following way:

- $\beta_1$ is significantly different from zero in the full model

  $$y = \alpha + \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2 + \varepsilon$$
- $\beta_2$ is not significantly different from zero in the full model.
- Either (a) $\beta_1=\beta_2$ or (b) a test of $H_0:\beta_1=\beta_2$ is not significant.  The latter is equivalent to the full model not being significantly better than the reduced model

  $$y = \alpha + \beta(x_1 + x_2) + \varepsilon.$$

**Intuitively,** $y$ must have a detectable linear relationship with $x_1$ but not with $x_2$, even though the coefficients ("slopes") of those relationships are the same.  This could happen when the spread of $x_1$ in the data is substantially greater than the spread of $x_2$: the wider spread of $x_1$ will induce greater changes in $y$, even when $\beta_1 \approx \beta_2$, making $\beta_1$ more readily detectable than $\beta_2$.

**To illustrate,** I played around with (a) the amount of data $n$ and (b) the variance of $\varepsilon$ to produce this phenomenon.  The data are

$$(x_1, x_2, y) = ((1, 2, \ldots, 2n), (1,\ldots,1,-1,\ldots,-1), x_1+x_2+\varepsilon)$$

where $\varepsilon$ are independently and identically distributed with a mean of zero and standard deviation of $3$.  As $n$ grows, $x_1$ becomes more spread out (from $1$ through $2n$) while $x_2$ is confined to the interval $[-1,1]$.  The *true* underlying relationship is $\alpha=0, \beta_1=\beta_2=1$.

The following is `R` code to generate this example.

```R
n <- 12
x1 <- 1:(2*n)
x2 <- c(rep(-1,n), rep(1,n))
set.seed(17)
y <- x1 + x2 + rnorm(2*n, sd=3)
```

1. Here is the fit of the full model.

   ```
   > summary(fit.full <- lm(y ~ x1+x2))

   Coefficients:
               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
   (Intercept)  -0.5223     1.8358  -0.284    0.779    
   x1            1.1400     0.1416   8.053 7.41e-08 ***
   x2            0.4886     0.9800   0.499    0.623
   ```

   $\beta_1$ is significant at any reasonable threshold ($p$ is essentially zero), while, $\beta_2$ is not significant at any reasonable threshold ($p=0.623$).
2. The full model is not a significant improvement over the full model ($p = 0.5618$):

   ```
   >fit.partial <- lm(y ~ I(x1+x2))
   >anova(fit.partial, fit.full)

   Analysis of Variance Table

   Model 1: y ~ I(x1 + x2)
   Model 2: y ~ x1 + x2
     Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq      F Pr(>F)
   1     22 122.36                           
   2     21 120.37  1    1.9924 0.3476 0.5618
   ```

Comment: Thanks, William, for the extensive and reasonable arguments! :) A short comment: `x2 <- c(rep(-1,n), rep(1,n))` will not give you a sequence of `(1, -1, 1, -1, ...)` but rather `(-1, -1,..., 1, 1)`. And if it is the former case, `x2` turns to be significant immediately. Anyway, I like your logic. Basically, it means that if I set `x1 <- rnorm(2*n, sd=5)`, `x2 <- rnorm(2*n, sd=0.1)`, and `y <- 1 + x1 + x2 + rnorm(2*n, sd=3)`, I should also get the very same result, as `x1` is much more spread out than `x2`. And I do, ***but*** it depends on seed. Should we expect it?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my incorrect description of $X_2$--it was a holdover from an earlier version of this answer. (I changed it in order to make the standardized variables orthogonal.) The result *should* depend on the random seed, especially because the sample size is relatively small (just 24 observations). Logically, all that matters is that there exist some dataset with these characteristics, but it's more satisfying to show how one might arise naturally in a realistic regression setting, as done here.

Comment: +1, @Alekz112, Andrew Gelman and Hal Stern had an American Statistician article about this exact question, see [*The difference between “significant” and “not significant” is
not itself statistically significant*](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/unpublished/signif3.pdf).

Comment: @whuber, to clear it out: do we care about orthogonality because it can lead to multicollinearity and, thus, to less efficient estimates, which could bias our conclusions about significance? Or is there another reason? Apart from the seed, the result depends on the sample size as well, but of course, you're right: it is sufficient to find just one case. And finally, after reconsidering my question, I would start the answer something like this: yes, it is possible, if the confidence interval of $\hat{\beta_2}$ includes both 0 and $\hat{\beta_1}$.

Comment: @AndyW, that is a really interesting article, it made some things in my head clear, thanks a lot for the reference!

Comment: (1) Orthogonality merely creates a clean separation between the independent variables. That simplifies calculations with them and reasoning about their roles in the regression. (2) The confidence interval criterion, although suggestive, is not correct. It is possible for the CI of $\hat\beta_2$ not to cover $\hat\beta_1$, yet for $\hat\beta_2 - \hat\beta_1$ not to be significantly different from zero.

Comment: I see I see, so if I say it's only possible, if the confidence interval of $\hat{\beta_2}$ includes both 0 and $\hat{\beta_1}$, then I test the hypothesis $\hat{\beta_1}=\hat{\beta_2}$, whereas we are interested in testing $\beta_1=\beta_2$. So we obviously miss some cases.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding that, because "$\hat\beta_1=\hat\beta_2$" is not a hypothesis.  It's only a statement about equality of *estimates*, which--as an assertion about the data--is either true or false for this particular dataset.

Comment: So if it turns out that CI for $\hat{\beta_2}$ does not include $\hat{\beta_1}$ but nevertheless $\hat{\beta_1} \approx \hat{\beta_2}$, then why could that happen? Because we're comparing $\beta_2$ with a particular point estimate $\hat{\beta_1}$ or am I wrong? Thank you for your patience and for clarifying many details!

Comment: The crux of the matter is that the variance of $\hat\beta_2-\hat\beta_1$ will typically be greater than either of the variances of $\hat\beta_2$ or $\hat\beta_1$. Thus the width of a CI based on $\hat\beta_2-\hat\beta_1$ could be substantially greater than the widths of CIs based on either estimate alone.